# Mensagens predeterminadas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `textarea` onde preciso adicionar textos predefinidos que estão meus links. Quando clicar nos mesmos, seja adicionado o conteúdo do `ID` na posição atual do cursor no `textarea`. Necessito fazer isso com **jQuery**.

Exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/e7kva60d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setar o conteúdo no `id` do campo não seria a melhor escolha. Lembrando que a função do `id` é guardar o identificador do seu campo para manipular o mesmo. para resolver seu problema e ficar mais semântico, aconselharia utilizar um campo data para guardar o valor conforme abaixo:

**HTML**:

```
<textarea name="descricao" class="form" rows="9"></textarea>
<a href="#" data-message="Bom dia, como voce esta?">Saudação</a>
<a href="#" data-message="texto do exemplo numero 2">Exemplo 2</a>
<a href="#" data-message="texto do exemplo numero 3">Exemplo 3</a>
<a href="#" data-message="texto do exemplo numero 4">Exemplo 4</a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function setarValor() {

    var menssagem = $(this).data('message'); //Pego a menssagem do campo data

    var textAreaPosition = $('textarea').prop("selectionStart"); //pego a posição do cursor no textarea

    var textAreaValue = $('textarea').val(); // pego valor do text area 

    var valorConcatenado = [textAreaValue.slice(0, textAreaPosition), menssagem, textAreaValue.slice(textAreaPosition)].join(''); // faço a concatenação da menssagem na posição

    $('textarea').val(valorConcatenado); //seto valor no textarea
}

//Ele execulta após toda a pagina ser renderizada
$(document).ready(function () {

    //seto de click nos seus links
    $('a').click(setarValor);
});
```

Segue [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/e7kva60d/7/) da alteração

Comment: Boa noite Bruno, Obrigado pela sua dica.

Comment: ficaria assim https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/e7kva60d/1/

Comment: O script esta funcionando, mas ele apaga o texto anterior quando clica em mais que um item, tem como fazer ele adicionar sempre e não apagar o texto anterior?

Comment: tem sim.. olhe nesse link https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/e7kva60d/3/ se for isso atualizo o post acima

Comment: Cara, esta 99%, vou colocar mais dificuldade :P Tem como colocar onde esta posicionado o mouse, ou seja entre duas frases por exemplo

"olá como esta
[QUERO COLOCAR AQUI]
Tudo bem sim etc etc"

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quis dizer com onde está posicionado o mouse.. poderia explicar :D Seria o conteúdo do link ?

Comment: Se você perceber ele adiciona a msg na ultima linha, então se quero adicionar uma mensagem predeterminada onde já existe um texto não consigo... tenta você escrever um texto qualquer e tentar adicionar uma msg na primeira linha.. não é vai ser possivel porque ele sempre adiciona na ultima linha... deu para entender?

Comment: O ideal é que ele adicionasse onde estive o click do mouse dentro do textarea...

Comment: acho que entendi, vou implementar ..

Comment: segue a implementação :D https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/e7kva60d/6/ é possíveis outras melhorias, tipo acionar espaço antes e depois da menssagem, mais isso vai de você

Comment: Por enquanto esta perfeito cara, muito bom mesmo. Me passa um e-mail  para eu pagar um almoço para você ;P

Comment: hahaha' que bom que deu certo.. se precisar estamos ai.. não esquece de fechar a pergunta :D